# How to redirect user to a page by an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, redirect

I have a login page where the user enters the email and password.
So, I was able to make an ajax call to another page for configuration of the data.
Now, if the email and password are correct then it must redirect the user to a new page called, "home".
I tried, but, it redirected the div to the page.
Any solutions?
Thanks in advance, everyone!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $(".login-form").on('submit',(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "verify/login.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:  new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $(".login-result").html(data);
                },
                error: function() 
                {
                }           
            });
        }));
    });
</script>
```

This is simple request code, its working completely fine.
Now, in the php file which is login.php.

```
if ($email == $dbemail && $password == $dbpassword) {
    header("location:home");
}
```

In this code the page, "home" is being shown in div, "login-result".

Comment: Cant you just use a standard `POST` form action instead of ajax if you want it to redirect?

Comment: Can you please paste your present code. I mean not working code.

Comment: In the ajax callback do `window.location = URL_TO_PAGE`

Comment: Please post your relevant code.  You can use `window.location.href = "www.example.com";`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that after the ajax request, `login.php` script sends header back to the browser with 302 (redirect) status code, then the browser sends another GET request for the home page, and the result of that request is returned as the success of ajax call. So, you put a complete home page inside `.login-result` div.

Now, if you just use `window.location` call inside success function, you will get all of the above plus another GET request for the home page.

One solution is to send the response as JSON object with success or error status. Example:

```
// login.php
if ($email == $dbemail && $password == $dbpassword) {
    die( json_encode( [ 'success' => 1 ] ) );
} else {
    die( json_encode( [ 'success' => 0, 'error' => 'invalid username or password' ] ) );
}
```

That way you will know whether the login was successful or not, and then you can choose the appropriate action (redirect or show error). Not to mention avoiding of unnecessary requests.

```
dataType: 'json',
success: function( data )
{
    if ( data.success ) window.location = "home.php"; // change location
    else $(".login-result").html( data.error );
}
```

Comment: What about sending back authorization tokens when not using cookies?